# How do I convert this to use event.code instead of event.keycode?

Tags: javascript

I need to change this so it isn't using the depreciated keycode?

```
if(event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 90) {
    //the key pressed was alphanumeric
}
```

I know how to do the a-z and the 0-9 but what about the special chars between (between 48 & 90 that are not a-z and 0-9)?

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate.  I did look first but I didn't find anything that includes the "keys" between, only the a-z and 0-9.  If it is a duplicate, could you share a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regex if it doesn't need to be `event.code`.

```js
if(event.key.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/)) {
    //the key pressed was NOT alphanumeric
}
```

`event.key`:

> The value of the key pressed.
> Accounts for modifiers keys that return CAPS and alternate chars.

`event.code`:

> The physical key on the keyboard.
> Doesn't care if you are holding a modifier like Shift.

Ref: https://keycode.info/